# ngx-bootstrap ERROR TypeError: _co.openModal is not a function

Tags: html, angular, function, ngx-bootstrap

I'm new with ngx-bootstrap, and I try to make modal from this site : https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals

this I got this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: _co.openModal is not a function
```

here is some snippets

```js
//app.component.ts file

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/modal-options.class';


 @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styleUrls:['app.component.css'],
  templateUrl:'app.component.html',
  //template:`<h1>Hello world</h1>`
})

export class AppComponent 
{
  title = 'ini tengah';
}

export class DemoModalServiceStaticComponent {
  public modalRef: BsModalRef;
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}
 
  public openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
  }
}
```

```html
<!--the HTML file-->

<!--call modal-->
<li><a href="#" (click)="openModal(template)">BUTTON</a></li>
<!--end-->

<!--Modal-->
<template #template>
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      This is a modal.
    </div>
  </template>
<!--enf of modal-->
```

I followed the website and received the error. Can anyone help me fix this error?

Please let me know if more snippets are needed.

Comment: can you mentioned your template name and typescript name in this question ?. The problem is you mismatched component name if your write the model template inside the app.component.html you can only write the typescript model pop in AppComponent.

Comment: I'm using default name, app.component.html and app.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this :

write `openModal` method inside the Appcomponent

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ini tengah';
  public modalRef: BsModalRef;
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

  public openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
  }
}
```

Comment: didn't think before it has to be in AppComponent, thanks again Mr. Chandru